# Process group in bash

Tags: bash, shell

In the following session, bash starts two distinct pipelines, but they share the same pgid.  When the `ls` pipeline is removed (so the distinct pipelines are not invoked in a subshell), the two pipes get distinct process groups.  What gives? In particular, is it correct behavior for the non-interactive shell to put distinct pipelines in the same process group?  Or am I misinterpreting something?

```
bash-3.2$ cat print-pgid 
#!/bin/sh
echo $$ starting in $(ps -o pgid= $$) >&2
bash-3.2$ ls | for i in a b; do ./print-pgid | ./print-pgid & done
bash-3.2$ 67396 starting in 67393
67395 starting in 67393
67397 starting in 67393
67398 starting in 67393

bash-3.2$ for i in a b; do ./print-pgid | ./print-pgid & done
[1] 67404
[2] 67406
bash-3.2$ 67404 starting in 67403
67403 starting in 67403
67405 starting in 67405
67406 starting in 67405

[1]-  Done                    ./print-pgid | ./print-pgid
[2]+  Done                    ./print-pgid | ./print-pgid
bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second example, the `for` loop is executed in the current, interactive shell, which has job control enabled. Job control requires each job to be in its own process group.

But when you pipe from `ls`, the `for` loop is executed in a subshell. Because it's not an interactive shell, there's no job control, so there's no need to put each pipeline in its own process group. So that entire subshell is just a single process group.

Comment: +1. To confirm this, you can run `set +m` to explicitly disable job control; then the version without the subshell will behave the same way as the version with the subshell, because job control is disabled in both cases.

Comment: Ah, job control...such an annoying feature!